# Display "Name" in case url parameters are absent

Tags: javascript, php

I am not sure whether this is right, but I request for your help where possible.

Below is my code. It displays the url parameters but in case of no parameters, its blank insted of displaying "Name"

```
<script>  
{
    var str = document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/Name/gi, "<?php echo $_GET['n'];  ?>");    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

<p id="id1">Name</p>
```

Comment: `<?php echo (isset($_GET['n']) ? $_GET['n'] : 'Name');  ?>`

Comment: Please post that as an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are changing all the HTML inside the demo id tag.

```
<div id="demo"> Name</div>
```

If res = 'My';

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

Result

```
<div id="demo">My</div>
```

Above line will overide any data inside id demo element with you definded HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to replace it if the query parameter exists. If not, just use the original:

```
var str = document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML; 

<?php if (isset($_GET['n'])) : ?>
    str = str.replace(/Name/gi, "<?= $_GET['n'] ?>");
<?php endif ?>

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
```